# Respawnear un objeto destruido C#

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y trate de varios metodos pero al destruir el objeto no respawnea 
por ejemplo:

```
    if (col.gameObject.layer == 12)
    {
        life = life - 1;

        if (life == 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
```

luego del desrtroy que deberia poner?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor cuando dices que tratas varias cosas, aclara siempre cuales, para que las respuestas no sean alguna de las que has intentado

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar pasar el gameobject de manera serializada mediante un prefab de la siguiente manera:

```
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject gameobject; //creas la variable donde recibes el game Object

    //con esta linea lo traerias devuelta, pasandole el gameobject, la posicion y la rotacion
    Instantiate(gameobject,transform.position,Quaternion.identity)

//si tu gameobject tiene rigidbody, bastaria con lo siguiente, le pasas un valor en positivo para la derecha o negativo para la izquierda
 gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector2(1, gameObject.transform.position.y);
```

en el caso que no sepas como crear un prefab, arrastra el gameobject a la bandeja donde puedes ver tus scripts, se generara un cuadrado celeste, arrastra ese cuadrado celeste hacia el gameobject donde tengas el script.

ej: arrastras el gameobject personaje a la bandeja, y el prefab que se generara se lo agregas al script desde el editor de unity.

Comment: Probe lo que dijiste y converti a los 2 "enemigos" en prefab pero cuando los destruyo spawnean pero se quedan quietos ahora ¿como haria para que se muevan como siempre?

Comment: edite mi respuesta agregando como mover al personaje, deberias agregar esa linea en el metodo update para que se ejecute constantemente y avanze